# Calculating how many dead pixels I have on my Monitor

Tags: display, lcd, dead-pixel, stuck-pixel

I think I have a (or several) dead pixels on my Acer 24" Monitor `(Model Name: HA240Y Part Number: MM.T97SI.001)`

Their policy says:

```
Dead Pixel Warranty Policy
The table below shows the allowable number of dead sub-pixels for the native resolution of the LCD panel. Your display can be replaced during the duration of the limited warranty period if the number of dead pixels is greater than the allowable number.

General policy:    
Native Resolution   Bright Sub-Pixel    Dark Sub-Pixel  Total Sub-Pixel
FHD     1920*1080   ≤ 2                 ≤ 5             ≤ 5
```

How can tell if I'm above `≤2    ≤5     ≤5`?

Comment: Send it back, let Acer determine that.

Comment: You manually count dead pixels. Is the real question "how to spot them?" or "how to make them show themselves?"? Or maybe "what is the difference between 'bright' and 'dark'?"? Or what?

Comment: There's a reddish dot that keeps being detected as a dead pixel. So is that above `≤2    ≤5     ≤5`. How do I determine that?

Comment: So "how to tell how many pixels belong to a dot?", right? Or "what does the `≤` symbol mean?"?

Comment: Umm.. yes. I didn't know how to phrase that question.

Comment: So... anyone knows how?